# I want to delete and element from a vector and simultaneously traverse it in c++ but my code is showing Runtime Error

Tags: c++, vector, c++17

This is my code for deleting and traversing simultaneously but this code is giving runtime error. but it is showing runtime error and don't even know where the error is

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
vector<int>v{1,2,2,3,4,5};

int n=v.size();

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   auto it=find(v.begin()+i+1,v.end(),v[i]);
   
   if(it!=v.end());
   {
    v.erase(it);
    n--;
   }
   
    cout<<v[i]<<" ";
 
}

    
    
}
```

Comment: `v.begin()+i+1` might be past `v.end()`.

Comment: Well, don't do that. Use `std::remove` or `std::remove_if`

Comment: Fear the deadly semi of doooooom! `if(it!=v.end()); <- death! Bloody DEATH!`

Comment: Unrelated: Only add one Language Standard tag. Usually you should pick the most recent.

Comment: It would be much simpler and better if you would tell us what exactly you are trying to accomplish with this your code. Also please specify the error that you get, as well as the way you are trying to compile your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vector `erase` function to delete the single first value.

```
std::find (vec.begin(), vec.end(), val_to_delete);
if(iter != vec.end())
     vec.erase(iter);
```

OR for multiple

```
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), val_to__delete), vec.end());
```

Comment: Note that with the first option, `n` will have to be reduced on successful removal or the `for` loop will shoot off the end of the container.